# How to add data-cy testing ids to d3 page

Tags: cypress

I'm testing a page developed with d3 (in javascript) and need to add `data-cy` attributes to the artifacts on the page, as per recommended best practices.

But all the examples I've found show how to add the ids to HTML, but in my app the HTML is generated.

For example,

```js
  var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 25)
      .attr("cx", width / 2)
      .attr("cy", height / 2)
      .style("fill", "#19d3a2")
      .style("fill-opacity", 0.3)
      .attr("stroke", "#b3a2c8")
      .style("stroke-width", 4)
      .call(d3.drag() // call specific function when circle is dragged
           .on("start", dragstarted)
           .on("drag", dragged)
           .on("end", dragended));
```

so how do I do it in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The d3 `.attr()` method is not limited to keys that are known to the d3 framework. You can just add the `data-cy` attribute this way.

However, you will need a ***unique*** id, and since the node is generated it will have to be part of the `data` that generates the circles

```js
var node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
      .attr("data-cy", (d, i) => d.name)
```

generates

```html
<circle data-cy="123" r="..." cx="..." cy="..." stroke="..." style="..."></circle>
```